# ¿Cómo se podría traducir al español neutro la expresión "nice catch!"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, españa, español-neutral

Hace pocos días me volví a encontrar con la expresión inglesa *nice catch!*, una vieja conocida a la que le llevo buscando traducción desde hace muchos años.

Se utiliza la expresión indicando que una persona ha sido capaz de atrapar con habilidad algo al vuelo. Por ejemplo:

[image: Nice catch!]

Como se ve, se usa mucho en béisbol y también en rugby, aunque yo personalmente la he visto en cómics, en situaciones en las que se atrapaba al vuelo otro tipo de objetos, e incluso personas.

Las opciones que tengo son:

> ¡Buena [atrapada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Jlhnqp)!

Pero me suena raro, y por lo que veo en la RAE se especifica que *atrapada* como sustantivo se usa solamente en Nicaragua, Puerto Rico y Venezuela (lo confirma también el diccionario de americanismos). La otra opción:

> ¡Buena [cogida](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9fN0kXt%7C9fPzurB)!

suena más erótico-festiva en según qué países, y en otros parece que estás felicitando al toro por cornear al torero. Así pues, ¿hay alguna expresión igualmente compacta en español neutro que refleje esta misma idea?

(Nota: si no se puede hallar una en español neutro, me sirve una en español de España.)

Comment: ¿Qué tal _buena captura_? También suena un poco raro pero podría ser otra opción

Comment: @blonfu podría ser, pero me suena más a cuando estás pescando y has atrapado un buen pez. Que si buscas "nice catch" en Google Imágenes no te creas que no salen fotos de tíos con peces enormes...

Comment: Jajaja! Pues si, ahora que lo dices encaja mejor con la pesca o con detener a un ladrón o algo así.

Comment: It is also now used in English figuratively as for instance if someone spots a mistake in your work you would say "Nice catch".

Comment: Coincido con @mdewey: también la he visto mucho en este contexto figurado (en [so] por ejemplo) y la traducía como _bien visto_. Fantástica foto por cierto, ¡la mujer está haciendo un doble _catch_!

Comment: @fedorqui el contexto que comenta mdewey no lo conocía, me será útil por si algún día hago _pair programming_ con un inglés, y ciertamente _bien visto_ sería una buena traducción. En todo caso, la pregunta original sigue siendo la misma. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una opción válida podría ser simplemente "¡Buena!". Puede usarse en varias ocasiones, transmitiendo el mismo sentimiento.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE], y gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: +1 Creo que cualquier intento por ser más específico terminaría, inevitablemente, rompiendo la neutralidad de la expresión. En Colombia sería universal "Anótese un punto" pero dudo que eso pueda ser español neutral.

Answer (score 3):

Es una frase que se utiliza en muchas situaciones. En su sentido figurado se refiere a que algo se ha hecho bien o realizado de una manera inteligente.

Varias propuestas según la situación serían:

- ¡Bien visto! // ¡Bien! // ¡Genial! - Si se utiliza, por ejemplo, cuando alguien se da cuenta de alguna cosa que el resto de personas no habían tenido en cuenta. Ejemplo específico:

  -Me he dado cuenta de que teníamos *este error concreto* en el planteamiento del problema.

  -¡Bien visto! // ¡Bien! // ¡Genial!
- ¡Buena! - Otro caso concreto es el que expones en tu pregunta, cuando se atrapa algo *literalmente*. Es decir, cuando nos tiran una pelota y se atrapa de una manera elegante o sorprendente.

Hay muchísimos otros casos según la situación, está claro, pero veo importante diferenciar entre su significado **literal** y su significado **abstracto**.

Comment: Buena respuesta Miquel y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Nótese que decimos [_darse cuenta de que_, no _darse cuenta que_](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/darse-cuenta-de-que-no-darse-cuenta-que-988/).

Comment: @fedorqui *¡Bien visto!* (y gracias) - Y Sí, estaba esperando a que alguien encontrara algún error semántico/gramatical a mi respuesta para poner este comentario hehe.

Comment: Jajaja, _¡buena!_ Ahora que [todos](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17840/1674) los [moderadores](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10485/1674) habéis pasado por aquí, tenemos que fortalecer la relación [es.so] - [spanish.se] :)

Answer (score 1):

Por dejar constancia aquí, acabo de oír en un episodio de *La doctora juguetes* la expresión ***¡buena pillada!*** o ***¡bien pillado!*** (una de las dos era seguro) en el contexto referenciado, que tampoco me parece mala opción.

Y añado otra: en *La patrulla canina* acaban de usar ***¡bien cogida!*** en el mismo contexto. Resulta curioso cómo cambia la expresión de pasar de usar "buena" a "bien". Y otra de la misma serie, y constatada que se ha usado para "nice catch": ***¡buenos reflejos!*** Curiosa manera de abordar la traducción.